# Error indices[0] = 0 is not in [0, 0) while training an object-detection model with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

So I am currently attempting to train a custom object-detection model on tensorflow to recognize images of a raspberrypi2. Everything is already set up and running on my hardware,but due to limitations of my gpu I settled for the cloud. I have uploaded my data(train & test records ans csv-files) and my checkpoint model. That is what I get from the logs:

`tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /mobilenet/model.ckpt`

`tensorflow:Starting Session.`

`tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt`

`tensorflow:Starting Queues.`

`tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>,
indices[0] = 0 is not in [0, 0)`

I also have a folder called images with the actual .jpg files and it is also on the cloud, but for some reason I must specify every directory with a preceeding forward slash / and that might be a problem, as I currently do not know whether some of the files are trying to import these images ,but could not find the path because of the missing /.
If any of you happens to share a solution I would be really thankful.

EDIT : I fixed it by downloading an older version of the models folder in tensorflow and the model started training, so note to the tf team.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue as you. Which version did you download exactly ? Much appreciated !

Comment: Hi , I guess it was this one http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017.tar.gz, but this is just the mobilenet model . It was about 7 months ago ,but you can always look at some old commits from that time . Hope it helped !

Comment: There must be something I'm missing but where can you get the previous models ? I'm looking for the ssd_inception_v2 but in the Model zoo the only available version is the one causing the  indices[0] = 0 is not in [0, 0) errors. (Edit : Thanks by the way)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the way I created TF Records worked out for me. Have a look at the following code -

```
 example = tf.train.Example(
                            features= tf.train.Features(
                                feature={
                                    'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
                                    'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
                                    'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename_str.encode('utf-8')),
                                    'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename_str.encode('utf-8')),
                                    'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
                                    'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_data),
                                    'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmin),
                                    'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmax),
                                    'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymin),
                                    'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymax),
                                    'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(labels_text),
                                    'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(labels),
                                }
                            )
                        )
```

Make sure that the TF Records have the same keys as the ones shown above. This is due to the fact that the model that you use would be expecting keys similar to the ones above. I hope this helps.

Earlier, I had made use of the following, which did not work out-

```
example = tf.train.Example(
                            features= tf.train.Features(
                                feature={
                                    'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(shape[0]),
                                    'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(shape[1]),
                                    'image/channels': dataset_util.int64_feature(shape[2]),
                                    'image/shape': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(shape),
                                    'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmin),
                                    'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmax),
                                    'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymin),
                                    'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymax),
                                    'image/object/bbox/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(labels),
                                    'image/object/bbox/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(labels_text),
                                    'image/object/bbox/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(difficult),
                                    'image/object/bbox/truncated': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(truncated),
                                    'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
                                    'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_data),
                                    'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename_str.encode('utf-8')),
                                    'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename_str.encode('utf-8'))
                                }
                            )
                        )
```

As you observe, I had written image/object/bbox/class/label instead of image/object/class/label. I hope this helps.

A place where you can check this out is the following link -https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using the centernet_mobilenetv2 model, but I just deleted the *num_keypoints* parameter in the pipeline.config file and then all was working fine. I don't know what is the problem with that parameter but I was able to run the training without it.